# how do I enable TMUX live preview window

Tags: tmux

I am using `tmux` terminal emulator to monitor a set of 100+ servers; I find it very useful that `tmux` has a preview feature, where I can see the last state of the given pane/window/session. `tmux` even has a mode where I can see multiple previews on the bottom half of the screen.

My problem is: these previews are NOT live, they DO NOT update as the terminal produces more output. Is there an option that would refresh these previews regularly? It would be very useful for me.

Comment: how many panes do you want to preview at the same time?